# Is there a threshold we can set for Search.Score (Azure Vector search) to ignore irrelevant results?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, vector-search

Azure cognitive Search (Vector Search) performs Cosine Similarity (Query vector vs Corpus). Is there a safe threshold, T to ignore results that are below T ?
Just want to have some similarities in query and results and ignore irrelevant results?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on the relevancy requirements in your application as well as the embedding model, so you'll need to do some experiments to check what score threshold would give you the desired results.

I recommend starting with a value in the high 0.7s or low 0.8s, such as 0.8.

I've included my reasoning below:

In high-dimensional vector spaces, any two randomly selected vector embeddings are more likely to be orthogonal due to a phenomenon called the "concentration of measure". This phenomenon arises from the geometry of high-dimensional spaces. In these spaces, most of the volume is concentrated near the surface of a hypersphere. This concentration of vectors makes it more likely randomly selected vectors to be orthogonal to each other. (Especially since many embedding models such as OpenAI's ada 002 generate normalized embedding vectors.)

This property is actually advantageous in machine learning tasks, such as embedding models used to vectorize data for vector search, because orthogonality between embeddings can improve certain aspects of learning. For example, orthogonal embeddings can help reduce interference between features, making the representations less entangled.

For the scores returned as @search.score during pure vector search, Azure Cognitive Search applies a transformation on cosine distance to produce a [monotonically decreasing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function). The score for an identical direction vector (meaning 0 degree angle) is 1. The score that Azure Search returns for orthogonal vector results is 0.5. A ~40 degree angle corresponds to 0.8. Thus, a score in the high 0.7s to low 0.8s would be a recommended starting point.

Comment: Is there a way in the query api to only return results above a specific similarity score?

Comment: Not at the moment. We are investing in improving this area. Stay tuned :)